# get heap dump from command line using jmx

Tags: jmx, heap-dump

Is it possible to get a server heap dump on a running process on linux (CentOS) using JMX from command line ?

can't open VisualVM,
can't install jmap

Answer (score 6):

It can be done with this simple code:

```
import com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.management.JMX;
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class CreateHeapDump
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String host = args[0];
        String port = args[1];

        JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + host + ":" + port + "/jmxrmi");
        JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);
        MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
        ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic");
        HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean bean = JMX.newMBeanProxy(mbsc, mbeanName, HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class, true);

        String fileName = "heap_dump_" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm").format(new Date()) + ".hprof";
        boolean onlyLiveObjects = true;
        bean.dumpHeap(fileName, onlyLiveObjects);
    }
}
```

Compile it:

```
javac CreateHeapDump.java
```

Call it from command line:

```
java CreateHeapDump localhost 9010
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't be pretty, but it works. Having said that, you might want to consider scripting this in Groovy or Jython, or even JavaScript....
I added a quickie add-on to [jmxlocal](https://github.com/nickman/jmxlocal), a project which implements standard JMX remoting for local JVMs. It now supports a command line invocation of one command against the connected MBeanServer, and the command must be specified in Java code.

Clone the repo and build with **mvn clean install**.
Copy the jar (**jmxlocal-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar**) to your target server.
Execute the dump JMX command using the PID of the target java process as follows:

```
java -jar target/jmxlocal-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -j service:jmx:attach:///<PID> -c "conn.invoke(on(\"com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic\"), \"dumpHeap\", new Object[]{\"/tmp/heap.dump\", true}, new String[]{String.class.getName(), boolean.class.getName()})"
```

The output will be

```
Command Executed. Result [null]
```

and you should find your dump file at **/tmp/heap.dump**.

If you need to, you can supply credentials using the **-u [username]** and **-p [password]** arguments.

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to find the Atach API. Please add tools.jar to the classpath`. any ideas ?

Comment: This usually happens if you're using the JRE (instead of the JDK) which does not have **tools.jar**.  That jar can be found in **$JDK_HOME**/lib.

Comment: So how can I fix it ? I obviously don't have JDK on target server. I tried copying tools.jar next to java, but still no success.

Comment: You don't ? Err.... ok. How about I patch it so that it will look for tools.jar in the same directory as the jmxlocal jar ?

Comment: Patch added. Try it now (from source)

Comment: I don't see any commits to the repository on github... are you sure you patched it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105059/discussion-between-nati-and-nicholas).

Comment: @Nati; Can't get to chat from work network. Added the heapdump built in. Implemented new command line handler. Much cleaner and easy to extend. Command: java -jar target/jmxlocal-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -jmxurl service:jmx:attach:///29431 -psx -c hdump    Result: Completed Successfully. Result:/tmp/29431-heap-2016-03-02-110323.dmp.    msg me through github if you have any issues.